# Self assessment: Entering in sideways loss relief from previous year

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, tax-deduction, self-employment, self-assessment

Any one au-fait with Self Assessment?

I am not sure where/how to fill in the online self assessment form to do this:

Claim previous year's losses in one business to claim relief on this years profits for another business.

It seems like it should be possible to do this (https://www.accaglobal.com/ca/en/technical-activities/technical-resources-search/2014/january/using-trading-losses.html) however I am not sure how to input it on the form.

Comment: Can you add a country tag, please? I'd guess UK, based on destination of link, and your other question, but it's best you confirm this.

Comment: It only allowed me 5 tags but I'm based in England, trying to fill in my 2018-2019 return @TripeHound

Comment: You could probably drop "taxes", as that is meant for questions not covered by a more specific tag, such as "income-tax". Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to the question, but there may be people watching the "united-kingdom" tag who can.

Comment: @TripeHound I'll try that then thank you for the suggestion

Comment: What are you reading in the link you gave that makes you think it's possible to transfer losses from one business to another like that? I might be missing it but I can't see where you are getting it from.

Comment: @Vicky I am not entirely sure which one but to be honest I am not sure as I may have misread... Are you confident that it is not possible to do this?

Comment: "Sideways losses can be used in the current and preceding tax years."...."Loss relief may also be carried forward to succeeding corporate trades." https://www.taxation.co.uk/Articles/2014-03-24-322311-momentary-lapse-reason#targetText=Early%20years'%20loss%20relief,first%20four%20years%20of%20trading. @Vicky

Comment: I’m not even slightly confident - I’ve never run a business myself or done anything other than simple personal self-assessment. I just didn’t think what you described was possible. I also found https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/business-income-manual/bim85700 which defines “sideways losses” and doesn’t say anything about different businesses.

Comment: 'general income' as opposed to income from a specific trade (On the same website you quoted from): S72 ITA 2007 - by reference to the individual’s general income of the three years before the year the loss was made. This only applies where the loss was made in the first four tax years in which the trade was carried on, see BIM85045 onwards. This relief is not available for losses of 2013-14 and subsequent years calculated using cash basis, see BIM70000 onwards. @Vicky

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice guide to what the self employed can do with losses here: https://www.litrg.org.uk/tax-guides/self-employment/working-out-profits-losses-and-capital-allowance/what-if-i-make-loss

The key list (there's more detail on each option on that page) seems to be:

1. You can use the loss in the current tax year and set it against all
   of your other income including income from savings. This reduces the
   tax that would otherwise be payable on your other income. This is
   also known as sideways loss relief.
2. You can carry the loss back to the previous tax year and set it against all of your income including income from savings. This
   reduces the tax due on this income, and a repayment of tax is
   usually generated.
3. For a new business, if the loss occurs in any of the first four years of trading you can set it against your total income of the
   three tax years immediately before the loss year, starting with the
   income of the earliest year first. This reduces the tax due on this
   income, and a repayment of tax is usually generated.
4. You can carry forward a loss and set it against profits of the same trade in a future year. This is generally the default position
   if the loss cannot be used in any other way. This is likely to
   reduce the tax that would otherwise be due in a future tax year.
5. If your business finishes and you make a loss in your last year, you can set this against your trading profits of the previous three
   years, latest year first. This reduces the tax due on this income,
   and a repayment of tax is usually generated.

I note none of the options is to carry losses across to another business.  However the first option listed above of setting it against other income would appear to achieve much the same result if the other business is profitable.  (I also note that [HMRC's SelfAssessment notes on the Self Employment pages](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/787406/sa103s_notes_2019.pdf) say things like "Carry your unused losses forward to set against any future profits **from the same business**")